# Correct way of passing data from one observable to other

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

I have two HTTP APIs -

1. Gets a list of tableNames
2. Gets a list of metadata

I am working on an Angular 5 application where the metadata (from 2nd API) before being displayed has to be modified by using the table names (from 1st API).

**Therefore, I see the task as follows-**
I have two observables. The first observable connects to the `tableNames API` and brings tableNames. The second observable connects to the `metadata API`, brings metadata and modifies the metadata according to the `tableNames API` output. I would like to keep the final product (modified metadata) as an observable which the angular application can subscribe to.

**Currently, the code looks currently looks something like below-**

```
private tablesNames: ReadonlyArray<String> | undefined;

this.getTablesNamesObservable().subscribe(
      tablesNames => { this.tablesNames = tablesNames; }
    );

// modify metadata uses tableNames to modify the metadata
this.modifiedMetadataObservable = this.metadataService.getOperatorMetadata()
                                      .map(metadata => this.modifyMetadata(metadata));
```

---

I didn't feel good about the code since I was assuming synchrony between two async operations. The doubt was proved right after reading [this article](https://medium.com/@paynoattn/3-common-mistakes-i-see-people-use-in-rx-and-the-observable-pattern-ba55fee3d031). So, using the approach suggested in the article, I changed the code to give tableNames as a parameter to generate new Observables and use switchMap (I could have used concatMap/flatMap but switchMap suited my requirements).

```
this.getTablesNamesObservable().switchMap(
      tableNames =>{this.metadataService.getOperatorMetadata()
                        .map(metadata => this.modifyMetadata(metadata, tableNames));}
      );
```

**Is this the correct way to go about this task or are there other better techniques to achieve this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `getTablesNamesObservable` and `getOperatorMetadata` are independent, it would make more sense to use `combineLatest`:

```
Observable.combineLatest(
  this.getTablesNamesObservable(),
  this.metadataService.getOperatorMetadata()
).map(([tableNames, metadata]) => this.modifyMetadata(metadata, tableNames));
```

Then `modifyMetadata` will be called whenever either observable emits a value.

By using `switchMap`, you unsubscribe and resubscribe to the observable returned by `getOperatorMetadata` whenever the observable returned by `getTablesNamesObservable` emits. And if they are independent - that is, `getOperatorMetadata` does not need to be passed the table names - doing do seems unnecessary.

If the observables each emit only a single value - or if you want only the last-emitted value of each - use `forkJoin` instead of `combineLatest`.